# Mongoose ES6 Class with static Getters

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to access a **Static Getter on a ES6 Class** loaded with Mongoose?

In my code below, I want to have access to static getter "STATUS", via mongoose model.

```js
const STATUS = {
    PRE_ACTIVE: 'pre-active',
    LIVE: 'live',
};

class Student {
    static get STATUS() {
        return STATUS;
    }

    static attributes() {
        return {
            name: {type: String, required: true},
            lastName: {type: String, required: true},
            language: {type: String, required: true},
            gender: {type: String, required: true},
        }
    }

    get fullName() {
        return `${this.name}_${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
const schema = new Schema(Student.attributes(), {timestamps: true});
schema.loadClass(Student);

const StudentMongoose = mongoose.model('Student', schema);
StudentMongoose.find({}); // -> OK

const instance = new StudentMongoose({name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', language: 'en', gender: 'male'});
instance.fullName; // -> OK

StudentMongoose.attributes(); // -> OK

StudentMongoose.STATUS; // -> NOK
```

Comment: `StudentMongoose != Student`. Why not just use `Student.STATUS`?

Comment: Because I only want to export StudentMongoose (as Student). So that I don't walk around with 2 objects.

Comment: @MiguelSantos did you find anything?

Comment: @HRK44 no, nothing.

Comment: Well you could just implement `STATUS` like you implemented `attributes`. The difference is purely semantic...